# ASP.NET MVC 2: Update Partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

Is it possible to call a controller action that will update (refresh) a partial within the View with the updated model? If so, can someone point me to an example?

I'm making an ajax call. The call sends some json to the controller. The controller extracts the json and formats it into XML that then get's passed on to a SPROC. The results of the SPROC update the model. This is where I need to update the view... with the latest model results.

Comment: Tell us more. Is this an ajax scenario?

Comment: @Matt, yes I'm using jQuery to make an ajax call. ajax sends json, my controller takes the json and converts it into a string to call a SPROC. I am trying to then take the updated model and pass it to the partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to have the action return the PartialView with its updated model. The calling code might look like this:

```
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
<%=Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "GetUpdatedPartialView", 
    new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "MyDiv"}) %>
```

When you click on the link, the HTML returned by your action will get placed into the div with ID "MyDiv".

**Edit**

I don't have my code with me, but if I remember right it's something like this:

```
var url = '<%=Url.Action("GetUpdatedPartialView")%>';
$.post(url, function(data) {$('#MyDiv').html(data);});
```

Comment: How can this be accomplished using jQuery ajax? I'm not using a actionlink, rather it's an ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you can just do something like:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
    return View(name_of_partial, updated_model);
}
```

On the front end, it's just a [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), something like:

```
$("#target-div").load(url_of_action, data_to_send);
```